# Optimization with parametric constraints: solution maps

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-smooth-optimization

For constrained optimization problems

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \min\limits_{x \in \mathbb R^n} & f(p, x) \\
\text{s.t.} & x \in C \end{array} $$

where $p \in \mathbb R$ is a parameter, we can deduce, under suitable convexity conditions, existence and Lipschitzness (in $p$) of solution maps $x^*(p) \in \arg\min\limits_{x \in C} f(p, x)$, say, by applying Theorem 2F.10 from this [Rockafellar's book](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=JSREAAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&ots=wJcJdJ-n1Y&sig=LWUmYfxUMKj8Z5KvoyrxAoqkCUs&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=2f.10&f=false). Here, I attached an excerpt from there:

[image: Theorem 2F.10]

**Question**: can we extend this result to the case when $C$ depends on $p$? Say, it is described by $g(p, x) \le 0$ with whatever properties required, like continuity in $p, x$, convexity in $x$ for each $p$.

The said book does not seem to contain a result in such a generic form.

One particular problem I see there is that the subgradients be pivoted to the static constraint. The argument collapses when the constraint changes

---

I'm almost sure that if the cost function is convex and the constraint doesn't change arbitrarily fast, the optimum must be continuous with a bounded rate of change

Comment: By writing the constraint as an indicator function term in the objective, it is clear that Thm 2F.10 cannot be used. Is there a convexity requirement? I am thinking about $f(x) = -x^2$ and $C=[-1,p]$ around $p=1$, where the argmin jumps between -1 and 1.

Comment: If you are just looking for any result, look at linear optimization.

Comment: yes, for example, see the book by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis (1997), section 5.2

Comment: @LinAlg Nothing like that in there. Anyway, I'm almost sure that if the cost function is convex and the constraint doesn't change arbitrarily fast, the optimum must be continuous with a bounded rate of change

Comment: Do you just want the existence of a continuous $x^*(p)$? Or do you also want it to be Lipschitz?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist It has to be Lipschitz in $p$, I believe.

Comment: I was not able to find Theorem 2F.10 in Rockafellar's book. It seems that the theorems are labelled differently there. Could you kindly point me to the page of the theorem?

Comment: @John It doesn't matter anymore. The answer is negative anyway

Comment: I believe the reference is off, it should be the book "Implicit Functions and Solution Mappings" by Dontchev and Rockafellar https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr208-ImplicitFns-DontRock.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, but also too long for a comment.

You may be interested in Berge's Maximum Theorem, which I quote below from [Aliprantis and Border (2006)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540295860) (Theorem 17.31). A *correspondence* $F\colon X \twoheadrightarrow Y$ is a set-valued function that maps each $x\in X$ into a subset $Y$. I will define continuity for correspondences after the statement of the theorem.

> **Theorem (Berge).** Let $\varphi\colon X\twoheadrightarrow Y$ be a continuous correspondence between topological spaces with nonempty
>   compact values, and suppose $f\colon X\times Y\to\mathbb R$ is
>   continuous. Define the "value function" $m\colon X \to \mathbb R$ by
>   $$ m(x) = \max_{y\in\varphi(x)} f(x,y), $$ and the correpsondence of
>   maximisers by $$ \mu(x) = \{ y \in \varphi(x) : f(x,y) = m(x) \}. $$
>   Then,
>
> 1. the value function is continuous;
> 2. the argmax correspondence $\mu$ is upper hemicontinuous and has nonempty compact values.

The statement of this theorem in Aliprantis and Border is actually slightly more general than this (they require only continuity of $f$ on the graph of $\varphi$), but I have taken liberties for simplicity.

A neighbourhood of a set $A$ is any set $B$ containing an open set $V$ such that $A \subset V \subset B$.

We say that a correspondence $\varphi\colon X \twoheadrightarrow Y$ is *upper hemicontinuous* (uhc) if for every $x \in X$, and every neighbourhood $U$ of $\varphi (x)$, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $z \in V$ implies that $\varphi (z) \subset U$.

A correspondence $\varphi\colon X \twoheadrightarrow Y$ is *lower hemicontinuous* (lhc) if for every $x \in X$ and every open set $U$ such that $\varphi (x) \cap U \neq \emptyset$, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\varphi (z) \cap U \neq \emptyset$ whenever $z \in V$.

A correspondence is continuous if it is both uhc and lhc.

One might wonder whether it is possible to find a continuous function $g$ such that $g(x) \in \mu(x)$ for each $x$, so that $g$ is a continuous selection from $\mu$. However, as we can see above, we can only guarantee that $\mu$ is uhc, and continuous selection theorems I am familiar with usually require that the correspondence we are selecting from be lhc.

However, since we know that $\mu$ is uhc, we also know that $\mu$ is continuous when viewed as a function from $X$ into $Y$ whenever we can guarantee that $\mu(x)$ is a singleton for each $x$. A sufficient condition for this is for $f$ to be strictly concave in $y$ for each $x$, with $\varphi$ being convex-valued (that is, $\varphi (x)$ is a convex set for each $x$).

To see this, suppose that $y,y^\prime \in \mu(x)$, with $y\neq y^\prime$. Then, from strict concavity of $f(\cdot ,x)$ and the fact that $\varphi(x)$ is convex, we have that, for $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $$ f(x, \alpha y + (1-\alpha) y^\prime) > \alpha f(x,y) + (1-\alpha)  f(x,y^\prime) = m(x)$$ and $\alpha y + (1-\alpha) y^\prime \in \varphi (x)$, a contradiction. This means that $\mu$ is uhc and singleton-valued, and is therefore continuous when viewed as a function.

Comment: Thanks. I know this theorem well. Should have probably mentioned that in the question. The problem is that it's just too general and, as you say, doesn't even claim a continuous solution map.
The answer, it feels, lies in different direction -- in a-la Rockafellar results.

Comment: @RubiShnol The solution map is uhc, which is a notion of continuity for set-valued maps. That said, if you can guarantee that $\mu (x)$ is a singleton for each $x$, then $\mu$ is continuous when viewed as a function. (Strict convexity of $f(x,\cdot)$ for each $x$ should suffice, I believe.)

Comment: That is what I am looking for and can't find. If you are aware of any literature in that direction, please share. It is quite obvious that the solution map is usc. To derive Lipschitzness like in the Rockafellar's book is qualititevaly more difficult.

Comment: @RubiShnol yes, being Lipschitz is a quite strong requirement. I edited my answer with some details about my last comment. I’ll let you know if something more related to what you’re looking for comes to mind.